# Get User Details from device on Android to speed up registration by populating fields

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is a way to get user information ( address, email, name, phone, etc. ).  I have found where I can use AccountManager to find possible email addresses as well as ContentResolver with ContactsContract in order to find the name.  I was wondering if there is a location where all of this can be read for purposes of auto filling a registration page to save the user time.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will only work for ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH and above:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Profile.DISPLAY_NAME));
                }
                c.close();
            }
```

Comment: When I tried this method earlier I was able to get the name of the user on device, but it still lacks the mailing/physical address of the user of the device.

Comment: you an get the contact Id and fire a query to get rest of the details

Comment: Ok, I see what your saying.  I don't know if I can get the address from the contact but I get how you can use the data from the contact.